# Libnetlink, gcc. undefined reference to rtnl_open

Tags: c, gcc, undefined-reference

I have a problem with using libnetlink.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <libnetlink.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

struct rtnl_handle* rth;
unsigned bitmap_socket_group;
if ((rtnl_open(rth,bitmap_socket_group))==-1)
{
    printf("Some sht happend\n");
    return -1;
}


return 0;
}
```

After that i'm running gcc -o rt route-test.c and it returns:

```
/tmp/ccvqPhGI.o: In function `main': route-test.c:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `rtnl_open'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

All i want is just to test libnetlink. As a helloworld.
Is it a problem with gcc arguments?
Hope for help:)

Comment: It appears you are either missing a header or your a failing to link against a needed library. Are you sure there is no `-lnetlink` you need to include in your compile string?

Comment: You're right, i need `-lnetlink`! Thank you:)

Comment: Chock one up of the educated `SWAG` (swinging wild-ass guess) `:)`  Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are either missing a header or your a failing to link against a needed library. Are you sure there is no `-lnetlink` you need to include in your compile string?
                    – David C. Rankin

You're right, i need `-lnetlink`! Thank you:)
                    – AlexZ

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/3/libnetlink/), you may need to include more librairies :

```
#include <asm/types.h>
#include <libnetlink.h>
#include <linux/netlink.h>
#include <linux/rtnetlink.h>
```

Comment: How does one obtain libnetlink.h? I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and when I try #include <libnetlink.h>, I get a "no such file or directory." error

Comment: @user1118764 `apt-get install iproute-dev` ?

Comment: As of Ubuntu 18.10, there is no longer an `iproute-dev` package. Do you have any suggestions now?

Comment: You may want to try to install `iproute2`

Comment: Looks like libnetlink-dev is no longer in Ubuntu. From what I can see, more recent library to replace this is the "minimal" netlink library ("libmnl"): `sudo apt-get install libmnl-dev`.